# Should GitHub Pages https:<moniker>.github.io/<repo> point to Read-the-docs build?

Tags: github, read-the-docs

I have a GitHub repo of docs linked to my RTD account.  The GitHub/RTD connection appears to be set up correctly with a functional webhook (green checks at both ends).  Commits to the repo trigger a successful build on RTD as expected.  RTD is an Authorized OAuth App and my RTD account is connected to my GitHub account.

Under Settings -> GitHub pages, I have tried both master branch and  master branch/docs.  I would expect https://moniker.github.io/repo-name/ to go to the connected RTD docs.   But it just shows the repo-name/README.md file, not the repo-name.rtfd.io docs.  Am I misunderstanding the linkage or the use of GitHub Pages?  Or am I completely missing something?  Thanks for any insight.

Comment: When you set the GitHub pages source to master/docs, what does the index.md or index.html in your docs/ directory contain?

Comment: The conf.py and index.rst are in docs/source/.   The index.rst has the introductory materials including the toctree and the indices/tables sections.  The results are at pierogi.rtfd.io (as I said, this was a test site).  The readthedocs.yaml file points to sphinx: docs/source/conf.py.  Thank you for looking at this.

Answer (score 0):

I put in a help desk question to GitHub and their response was:

*GitHub Pages provides its own web hosting and will not integrate with external services. If you're publishing your site elsewhere GitHub Pages will not link to it.*

So the answer is "no", adding the webhook only triggers a new build on commits and I do explicitly need a docs/index.html (or .md) that redirects to the RTD documentation.